# Error when trying to use cursor to get integer values from SQLite in Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-cursor

I'm trying to get integer values, to be displayed in a listview from SQLlite using cursors but it shows the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 4 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.

Here are my code

MyItems.java:

```
public  ArrayList<SalesItemInformationLV> retrieveAllForlist(Context c)
{
    ArrayList<SalesItemInformationLV> items = new ArrayList<SalesItemInformationLV>();

    Cursor myCursor;
    String mystring = "";

    MyDbAdapter db = new MyDbAdapter(c);
    db.open();
    //contactIdList.clear();
    //contactList.clear();
    myCursor = db.retrieveAllEntriesCursor();

    if (myCursor != null && myCursor.getCount() > 0)
    {
        myCursor.moveToFirst();
        do {
            contactIdList.add(myCursor.getInt(db.COLUMN_KEY_ID));
            items.add(new SalesItemInformationLV(myCursor.getString(db.COLUMN_NAME_ID), myCursor.getInt(db.COLUMN_QTYSOLD_ID)));
        } while (myCursor.moveToNext());
    }
    db.close();

    return items;
}
```

MyDbAdapter.java:

```
private SQLiteDatabase _db;
private final Context context;

public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
public static final int COLUMN_KEY_ID = 0;
public static final String ENTRY_NAME = "entry_name";
public static final int COLUMN_NAME_ID = 1;
public static final String ENTRY_QTYSOLD = "entry_qtysold";
public static final int COLUMN_QTYSOLD_ID = 4;

private MyDBOpenHelper dbHelper;
//private MyDBOpenHelper dbHelper2;

public MyDbAdapter(Context _context)
{
    this.context = _context;
    
    //step 16 - create MyDBOpenHelper object
    //constructor
    dbHelper = new MyDBOpenHelper(context, DATABASE_NAMEA, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    //constructor
    //dbHelper2 = new MyDBOpenHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME2, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

public Cursor retrieveAllEntriesCursor() {
    //step 21 - retrieve all records from table
    Cursor c = null;
    try {
        c = _db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ID, ENTRY_NAME}, null, null, null, null, null);

    }
    catch (SQLiteException e)
    {
        Log.w(MYDBADAPTER_LOG_CAT, "Retrieve fail!");
    }

    return c;
}
```

I suspect the error comes from MyItems.java, but I'm having a hard time figuring out what's the error.

Comment: You are loading predefined schema?

Comment: post code of `retrieveAllEntriesCursor()` method also

Comment: @chandil03 it's in the 2nd grey box

Comment: If possible post your schema

Comment: you are fetching `KEY_ID` at 0 index and `COLUMN_KEY_ID` is 3 thats why this error is occurred. try using 0 instead of `COLUMN_KEY_ID`. it should work.

Comment: @chandil03 which part of the code says that `COLUMN_KEY_ID` is 3?

Comment: value of COLUMN_KEY_ID constant is 3 i guess. your exception says. sorry its  4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are fetching only 2 columns(`KEY_ID, ENTRY_NAME`) from database and while reading you are expecting 3 columns.

```
 c = _db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ID, ENTRY_NAME}, null, null, null, null, null);
```

You are trying to get value from column 4, which is throuing an error.

```
public static final int COLUMN_QTYSOLD_ID = 4;
```

Comment: Then please check mapping of column numbers

Answer (score 0):

**Use this method  in your databasehelper class**

```
public Cursor getalldata() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery(" select * from " + TABLE_Name, null);

    return res;


}
```

**and call this method where you want to get your data from database table **

```
 public void getdata(){

    Cursor res = db.getstafdata(); //db id an object of database helper //class
    if (res.getCount() == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "no data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } else {

        StringBuffer stbuff = new StringBuffer();
        while (res.moveToNext()) {

            detail.add(new doctor_details(res.getString(1),res.getString(2),res.getString(3)));

        }


}
```

}